# socket.io client not able to connect and receive messages emit by server

Tags: socket.io

I am emitting messages from socket.io server running on port 8001
but my socket.io client not able to connect and receive these messages

my index.html (client):

```
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-4.0.0.js"></script>
    <script>
      //var socket = io();
      //var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8001');
      var socket = io('http://localhost:8001', { transports : ['websocket'] });
      socket.on('connect', function(){
        console.log("connected");
        socket.on("message", data => {
          console.log(data);
        });
      });
    </script>
```

My nodejs server code:

```
    const app = require("express")();
    const server = require("http").createServer(app);
    
    const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
        cors: {
          origin: '*',
        }
      });
    
    io.on("connection", () => {
        console.log("Connected!");
    });
    
    var redis = require('redis');  
    //var url = "redis://:@localhost:6379"; 
    //var redis = require('redis-url').connect();
    //var client = redis.createClient(url);  
    var client = redis.createClient();  
    //var client = redis.createClient();
    client.on("error", function(error) {
      console.error(error);
    });
    client.subscribe('notification');
    client.on('message', function(channel, msg) {  
      console.log("Message received: "+msg);
      io.sockets.emit(msg);
    });
    
    console.log('starting server on 8001...');
    server.listen(8001);
```

My node js server console logs:

```
starting server on 8001...
Message received: from laravel
```

Comment: I changed cdn <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/3.1.3/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha384-cPwlPLvBTa3sKAgddT6krw0cJat7egBga3DJepJyrLl4Q9/5WLra3rrnMcyTyOnh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
it is connected now, but I am not receiving message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
io.sockets.send(msg);
```

this worked for me. also make sure you are using the same version of socket.io on both client and server